# How to fix background color unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing a unit test for a component styled with emotion.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

const Selected = styled.div`
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  background: ${props => props.color};
`;

const SelectedColor = ({ color }) => {
  return <Selected color={color} />;
};
```

I've written this test, but it never passes.

```
  it('Should change the background color', () => {
    const color = 'rgb(140, 52, 30)';

    const { container } = render(<SelectedColor color={color} />);

    expect(container).toHaveStyle(`background: ${color}`);
  });
```

Comment: When you run the actual app, what's the background color if you check it in the devtools window?

Comment: background: rgb(0,0,0);

Answer (score 4):

As per documentation, container is rendered within a `div`, so you need to check `container.firstChild` in this case.

https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#container-1

This is how the test will end up being:

```
const color = 'rgb(140, 52, 30)'; 
const { container } = render(<SelectedColor color={color} />); 
expect(container.firstChild).toHaveStyle(`background: ${color}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason in Typescript `container.firstChild` isn't an HTMLElement but `container.children[0]` is... So if you are using TS, better use the latter.